# CSS: Changing div's property on another div's a:hover. Possible ? How?

Tags: html, css

Refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCbVs/5/) Please.
What I am trying to do is on hovering on `a`-tag inside `#menu ul li`, the `background-color` color of `#header-bottom` must also changed as of similar to `background-color` of the `a`-tag.
How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**
Done this with CSS only yippie! :) [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCbVs/14/)

Comment: I'm not a Javascript ninja, but I think what you are looking for is changing the style attribute with an `onmouseover()`.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do this with css and your current structure. There isn't a way to link a child element back up the DOM to influence a parent (hence the `cascading` part of `CSS`).

Comment: I am eagerly looking for some CSS trick only? Is there a way?

Comment: can I do this if my `menu` _links_ are direct childs of `#menu` rather than `li`?

Comment: If you can get `header-bottom` to be a sibling of the `li` or `a` tags then I think something can be worked out. Javascript can solve this problem easily which is what I would do.

Comment: @Asif - yes, try dumping the list and using inline-block divs instead. Place `header-bottom` as the last child. You can then have a hover event target both elements. `#menu div:hover, #menu div:hover + #header-bottom { background: black; }`

Comment: @mrtsherman if javascript is the only way then your welcome to help me out.

Comment: What do you have against javascript? This is what's it's designed for.

Comment: I am not against javascript at all, but its just a thing I want to keep it javascript free or you can say that want to keep it _only CSS_ thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a jQuery method (sorry too much effort to make this javascript only for me). It could be translated though.

http://jsfiddle.net/PCbVs/9/

```
$('.menu').hover(

function() {
    var color = $(this).css('borderLeftColor');
    console.log(color);
    $('#header-bottom').css('backgroundColor', color);
}, function() {

});​
```

Or with jQuery UI animated style transitions.

http://jsfiddle.net/PCbVs/10/

```
$('.menu').hover(

function() {
    var color = $(this).css('borderLeftColor');
    console.log(color);
    $('#header-bottom').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: color }, 500);
}, function() {

});​
```

Comment: Thanks @mrtsherman! one thing left, the color of `#header-bottom` wikk have to changed to the `current` menu-item on mouse exit, say, if i am on `product` page, the default color should be that of product's border, on mouse enter the color should change to respective menu-item's border-color finally on mouse-exit, the color should revert back to that of default current's menu-item's. . . I hope i am clear..

Comment: Add an `active` class to the current link. Then on mouse out restore the color. http://jsfiddle.net/PCbVs/11/